# What exactly is XBTC?

Tags: terminology

What is xbtc? I saw many articles refered xbtc,just like "btc to xbtc". But there's no material telling what it exactly is.

Comment: Did you mean to ask about XBT?  XBTC seems to be some company unrelated to Bitcoin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XBTC is an asset representation of BTC in [Counterparty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterparty_%28technology%29).
Apparently, you could send Bitcoin to a Counterparty gateway, and get the same amount of XBTC back in turn. These could then be traded for other Counterparty assets. The operator of that gateway claimed that it was cheaper to trade thusly than on Bitcoin exchanges.

I've found an announcement for a XBTC gateway here: [XBTC Gateway released](https://forums.counterparty.io/discussion/404/ann-xbtc-gateway-released). It appears to me that the service has since been [shut down due to regulatory concerns](https://forums.counterparty.io/discussion/761/quick-buy-update-from-vennd-io).

Comment: I thought it's sort of a bitcoin unit. now i'm cleared with this term.

Answer (score -1):

XBTC is the combination of  ISO 4217 currency code XBT and the name BTC, which is also commonly used to represent one bitcoin, but it violates ISO 4217 because it begins with "BT", the country code of Bhutan.

This is what is known as a blended word, which Lewis Carroll called portmanteaus, naming them after a suitcase that unfolds into two equal parts.

Comment: Who uses it? What does it represent?

Comment: Mostly Bitcoiners. It represent bitcoin and Bitcoin services.

Comment: If you read the question,  you'll see that it refers to a unit that can be traded in exchange for Bitcoin, so a) it's not the same as Bitcoin and b) it's a currency unit. I don't think this question has anything to do with your website. Otherwise, please elaborate.

Comment: Not only my site use this abbreviation. It concerned many other services. But I can't find the place where btc/xbtc can be exchanged or converted. If you know such a place - please point it.